# What are the differences between defaultValue and value in select?

Tags: reactjs, html-select

I have two react components, parent and child. I'm passing a prop to a child component, and I want to use that prop to set the defaultValue on a select input. However, if that property changes, I'd like for the select default value to change as well.

When I set default value in `select`, I can choose one of the options that is a part of that selector. If I use value instead, the 'default' changes as the property updates, but I can't select any of the options.

```
class Selector extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
       <select defaultValue={this.props.value}>
         <option>1</option>
         <option>2</option>
       </select>
    )
  }
}
```

I'd like for the value to change, and I realize that it is not re rendering even though the prop has changed. I'm looking for a work around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you don't have `onChange` handler you need to put your value as `defaultValue`, but in `value` when you have `onChange` handler.

You can do this,

```
class Selector extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selected: props.value
    }
  }
  change = (event) =>{
     this.setState({selected: event.target.value});
  }
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (prevState.selected !== this.props.value) {
      this.setState({selected: this.props.value})
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
       <select value={this.state.selected} onChange={this.change}>
         <option>1</option>
         <option>2</option>
       </select>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I actually had an onChange handler but I wasn't checking using the lifecycle componentDidUpdate()!

Answer (score 4):

I'm quoting:

> The difference between the `defaultValue` and `value` property, is that
> `defaultValue` contains the default value, while `value` contains the
> current value after some changes have been made. If there are no
> changes, `defaultValue` and `value` is the same.
>
> The `defaultValue` property is useful when you want to find out whether
> the contents of a text field have been changed.

What that actually means is that if you put **defaultValue**, this value will be initialized to the input and that's it, you can change value and the text will change.

But if you put **value**, you would need to change that value given to the input in the first place in order for input text to change.

*Look at this example, all using the same state, but behaving differently.*

```js
// Example class component
class Thingy extends React.Component {
  
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { value: 'test' }
  }
  
  onChange(e) {
    this.setState({ value: e.target.value });
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div><b>default value</b> (you can edit without changing this.state.value)</div>
        <input defaultValue={this.state.value}></input>
        
        <div><b>value</b> (you can't edit because it does not change this.state.value)</div>
        <input value={this.state.value}></input>

        <div><b>value</b> (you can edit because it has onChange method attached that changes this.state.value) <br /> <b>NOTE:</b> this will also change second input since it has attached the same state with <b>value</b> property, but won't change first input becase same state was attached as <b>defaultValue</b></div>
        <input value={this.state.value} onChange={e => this.onChange(e)}></input>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <Thingy />,
  document.body
);
```

```css
div > div {
  font-size: 16px;
}

input + div {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

> defaultValue is selected value while very first time loading 
>   and
>   value is selected value every time to change option value