# How to change form inputs in React and post using axios?

Tags: reactjs

I'm learning React, but not strong yet. I use a component with form, that recieve data from express backend using axios. 
There is no problems with get the correct data and render it in the form inputs, but i can't cope how to change input values and post using axios. I read something about handleChange() and other staff, but it's too hard yet.

The JSON looks like this:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "_id": "5d28a6fcec97b111c2f5867d",
            "phone": "+1 (111) 111 11 11",
            "email": "shutruk@gmail.com",
            "title": "khkjhkjhkj",
            "longTitle": "lkjlkjlkjlk",
            "introTitle": "Shutruk",
            "introLongTitle": "Shutruk-Nahhunte",
            "videoLink": "khkjhkjhkj",
            "introText": "lkjlkjlkjlk",
            "__v": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is the component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class Misc extends Component {
  state = {
    data: [],
    loading: true,
    error: false,
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('http://localhost:5555/data')
      .then(res => {
        const data = res.data.data; // get the data array instead of object
        this.setState({ data, loading: false });
        console.log(data);
      })
      .catch(err => { // log request error and prevent access to undefined state
        this.setState({ loading: false, error: true });
        console.error(err); 
      })
  }
  render() {
    if (this.state.loading) {
      return(
        <div>
          <p> Loading... </p>
        </div>
      )
    }
    if (this.state.error || !this.state.data[0]) { // if request failed or data is empty don't try to access it either
      return(
        <div>
          <p> An error occured </p>
        </div>
      )
    }
    return (
      <form action="">
        <h2 className="center" >Change data</h2>
        <div className="center"><img src={require('../img/orn.png')} alt="" className="orn"/></div>
        <h5>Phone:</h5>
        <input type="text" value={ this.state.data[0].phone } />
        <h5>Email:</h5>
        <input type="text" value={ this.state.data[0].email } />
        <h5>Title:</h5>
        <input type="text" value={ this.state.data[0].title }/>
        <h5>Longtitle:</h5>
        <input type="text" value={ this.state.data[0].longTitle }/>
        <h2 className="center" >Intro:</h2>
        <div className="center"><img src={require('../img/orn.png')} alt="" className="orn"/></div>
        <h5>Title:</h5>
        <input type="text" value={ this.state.data[0].introTitle } />
        <h5>Longtitle:</h5>
        <input type="text" value={ this.state.data[0].introLongTitle } />
        <h5>Link to video:</h5>
        <input type="text" value={ this.state.data[0].videoLink } />        
        <h5>Text:</h5>
        <textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10" value={ this.state.data[0].introText }></textarea>
        <button type="submit" className="btn-large waves-effect waves-light xbutton">Save</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default Misc;
```

Many many thanks for any help!))

Comment: Check out [Difference between defaultValue and value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56988752/what-are-the-differences-between-defaultvalue-and-value-in-select/56988770#56988770)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can do it.

```
handleChange(key, value){
   const data = this.state.data;
   data[0][key] = value;
   this.setState({data});
}

handleSubmit(){
 // You can make post call here.
}

render() {
    if (this.state.loading) {
      return(
        <div>
          <p> Loading... </p>
        </div>
      )
    }
    if (this.state.error || !this.state.data[0]) { // if request failed or data is empty don't try to access it either
      return(
        <div>
          <p> An error occured </p>
        </div>
      )
    }
    return (
      <form action="" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>
        <h2 className="center" >Change data</h2>
        <div className="center"><img src={require('../img/orn.png')} alt="" className="orn"/></div>
        <h5>Phone:</h5>
        <input type="text" value={ this.state.data[0].phone } onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, "phone")}/>//Here you have to pass key in this case it's phone
        <h5>Email:</h5>
        <input type="text" value={ this.state.data[0].email } />
        <h5>Title:</h5>
        <input type="text" value={ this.state.data[0].title }/>
        <h5>Longtitle:</h5>
        <input type="text" value={ this.state.data[0].longTitle }/>
        <h2 className="center" >Intro:</h2>
        <div className="center"><img src={require('../img/orn.png')} alt="" className="orn"/></div>
        <h5>Title:</h5>
        <input type="text" value={ this.state.data[0].introTitle } />
        <h5>Longtitle:</h5>
        <input type="text" value={ this.state.data[0].introLongTitle } />
        <h5>Link to video:</h5>
        <input type="text" value={ this.state.data[0].videoLink } />        
        <h5>Text:</h5>
        <textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10" value={ this.state.data[0].introText }></textarea>
        <button type="submit" className="btn-large waves-effect waves-light xbutton">Save</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

You can more read it on form control https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html

Answer (score 2):

One of the major differences between React and Vue/Angular is the focus on *one-way databinding*. While you supply a `value` through state to the input components, they cannot *themselves* update your state when changes happen.

From the [React Docs on Forms](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html):

> In HTML, form elements such as `<input>`, `<textarea>`, and `<select>` typically maintain their own state and update it based on user input. In React, mutable state is typically kept in the state property of components, and only updated with `setState()`.

We call this *controlled components*. The component state is the single source of truth, and state can only explicitly be changed by `setState`. You would typically do this in -- as you said -- a change handler:

```js
class MyForm extends React.Component {
  state = {
    name: ''  
  };
  
  handleChange = (evt) => {
    // evt is a change event
    this.setState({
      name: evt.target.value,
    });
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <input type="text" value={this.state.name} onChange={this.handleChange} />
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyForm />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

This can of course be cumbersome, especially with many different types of inputs. However it is easy to reason about where changes come from.

You can also use *uncontrolled components*, where you often supply your inputs with default values. These inputs can change their value, but it will **not** be reflected in your state. You can use *refs* to read their value when needed:

```js
class MyForm extends React.Component {
  state = {
    name: 'Foo'  
  };
  
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.inputRef = React.createRef();
  }
  
  handleSubmit = (evt) => {
    evt.preventDefault();
    const name = this.inputRef.current.value;
    console.log({ name });
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <input ref={this.inputRef} type="text" defaultValue={this.state.name} />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyForm />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```